# plotting data with too many zero on x axis

Tags: gnuplot

I have this data1.dat data that I'd plot using gnuplot.

```
x        y
0.007   3.09216
0.008   3.60607
0.009   5.86643
```

then I tried to plot this with this plot script

```
set terminal svg size 400,300 enhanced fname 'arial'  
set output 'out2.png'

set xlabel 'diameter'
set ylabel 'number density'
set title 'density number plot'
plot  "data1.dat" using 3:4 title "" with lines
```

and the output in the x axis was like this
[image]

how to convert the number data on the x axis so it only shows only for example 7 or 8 only? this is an example and probably my data would getting bigger, so i can't change the data on data1.dat one by one in the x column, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, gnuplot's tic algorithm doesn't take the length of the ticlabels into account. That's why the numbers are overlapping.
You can do the following:

- set the xtic increment manually to avoid overlap, e.g. `set xtic 0.0005`
- multiply your values by a factor, e.g. 1000, especially if you have meters you can display millimeters, i.e. `($1*1000)` which is identical to `(column(1)*1000)`.

**Code:**

```
### avoid overlap of tic labels
reset session

$Data <<EOD
x        y
0.007   3.09216
0.008   3.60607
0.009   5.86643
EOD

set ytics 1
set multiplot layout 3,1

    set xlabel 'diameter / m'
    plot  $Data using 1:2 w l notitle

    set xlabel 'diameter / m'
    set xtic 0.0005
    plot  $Data using 1:2 w l notitle

    set xlabel 'diameter / mm'
    set xtics 0.2
    plot  $Data using ($1*1000):2 w l notitle

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: thanks, your suggestion works well for my problem